# pylibmc - how to support values greater than 1 MB

Tags: python, memcached, libmemcached, pylibmc

I'm already running memcached with the -I 3m option.

But do I need to tell pylibmc about the size change?

I tried this:

```
self.cache = memcache.Client(servers, binary=True,
    server_max_value_length=(1024 * 1024 * 2),
    behaviors={"tcp_nodelay": True, "ketama": True, "no_block": True})
```

But I got this:

```
File "utils.py", line 63, in init
behaviors={"tcp_nodelay": True, "ketama": True, "no_block": True})
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_max_value_length'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it seems to work fine without including 'server_max_value_length' in the init so I guess nothing special to do on the pylibmc end?